# Issue uploading files in spring boot java to onedrive using API

Tags: java, spring-boot, azure, microsoft-graph-api, postman

```
@GetMapping("/authorize")
public String authorize() {
    return "redirect:" + tokenUrl + "?client_id=" + clientId +
            "&redirect_uri=" + redirectUri +
            "&response_type=code" +
            "&scope=" + scope;
}

@GetMapping("/callback")
public String callback(@RequestParam("code") String code) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Entering callback method");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED);
        MultiValueMap<String, String> map = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
        map.add("client_id", clientId);
        map.add("client_secret", clientSecret);
        map.add("code", code);
        map.add("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
        map.add("grant_type", "authorization_code");
        HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, String>> request = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);
       
        String tokenurl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token";
        
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(tokenurl, request, String.class);
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
            String jsonResponse = response.getBody();
            ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            JsonNode root = objectMapper.readTree(jsonResponse);
            System.out.println(jsonResponse);
            accessToken = root.get("access_token").asText();
            System.out.println("accesstoken as a response :"+accessToken);
            return "redirect:/upload";
        } else {
            System.out.println("Error Occurs");
            return "error";
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error Occurs" + e);
        return "error";
    }
}

@PostMapping("/upload")
@ResponseBody
public String uploadFile(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    try {
        System.out.println("Headers Upload !!!");
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);            
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        byte[] byte1 = file.getBytes();
        
        HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(byte1, headers);
        //Error
        System.out.println("\n"+requestEntity+"\n"+requestEntity.getBody()+"\n");
        System.out.println(uploadUrl + "/" + folderId + "/items/" + file.getOriginalFilename() + ":/content");
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                uploadUrl + "/" +  file.getOriginalFilename() + ":/content",
                HttpMethod.PUT, 
                requestEntity,
                String.class);
        System.out.println("Response : "+response.getBody());
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED) {
            return "File uploaded successfully!";
        } else {
            return "Something went wrong !!!";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error Occurred " + ex.getMessage());
        return "Something went wrong !!! ";
    }
}

@PostMapping("/uploadf")
public String uploadfile1() {
    try {
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);            
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        
        // Read file content and encode it as Base64
        Path filePath = Paths.get("C:\\Users\\91638\\Documents\\Hello.docx");
        byte[] fileContent = Files.readAllBytes(filePath);
        String fileContentBase64 = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileContent);
        
        // Create JSON payload with the file content
        Map<String, String> requestBody = new HashMap<>();
        requestBody.put("file_content", fileContentBase64);
        
        // Serialize the map to JSON
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String requestBodyJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestBody);
        
        // Create HttpEntity with the JSON payload
        HttpEntity<String> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(requestBodyJson, headers);

        // Send the request
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                uploadUrl + "/Hello.docx:/content",
                HttpMethod.PUT, 
                requestEntity,
                String.class);
        
        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED) {
            return "File uploaded successfully!";
        } else {
            return "Something went wrong!";
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Error Occurred: " + ex.getMessage());
        return "Something went wrong!";
    }
}

@PostMapping("/upload1")
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestBody byte[] fileBytes) {
    try {
        // Prepare the request headers
        ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        String content = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(fileBytes);
        Map<String, String> requestBody = Collections.singletonMap("content", content);
        String jsonBody = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(requestBody);
        System.out.println(jsonBody);
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        // Create a request entity with the file bytes and headers
        HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(fileBytes, headers);

        // Prepare the upload URL
        

        // Make the HTTP PUT request to upload the file
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                uploadUrl + "/" +  "person.csv" + ":/content",
                HttpMethod.PUT,
                requestEntity,
                String.class);

        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully!");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatusCode()).body("Something went wrong: " + response.getStatusCode());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error uploading file: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
}

@PostMapping("/uploadj")
public ResponseEntity<String> uploadFile(@RequestBody String jsonPayload) {
    try {
        // Assuming the JSON payload contains the file content
        byte[] fileBytes = jsonPayload.getBytes();

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        headers.set("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

        // Create a request entity with the file bytes and headers
        HttpEntity<byte[]> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(fileBytes, headers);

        // Prepare the upload URL (replace with your actual upload URL)
       
        // Make the HTTP PUT request to upload the file
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(
                uploadUrl + "/" +  "person.txt" + ":/content",
                HttpMethod.PUT,
                requestEntity,
                String.class);

        if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.CREATED) {
            return ResponseEntity.ok("File uploaded successfully!");
        } else {
            return ResponseEntity.status(response.getStatusCode()).body("Something went wrong: " + response.getStatusCode());
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        return ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR).body("Error uploading file: " + ex.getMessage());
    }
```

this is the code im working i tried whole different way to upload my file using postman but each mapping provide different errors

one provide entity only allows writes with a JSON Content-Type header.

if i provide the actual json data it throw bad argument error its so frustrating to upload my file kindly someone help me to get rid of this I use gpt, gemini, github, etc nothing helps